# Generating and mutating state in vuex

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am using the Array() constructor to create an empty array of size 3 then filling it using forEach() or Array.fill() but when I try to change/mutate any element inside the array the value of any similar member in the other array is set to the last value assigned to any other member.
Creationn method:

```
const createBoard = () => {
  let row = Array(3);
  const cellDS = {
    isClcicked: false,
    toPlayer: null,
    cellID: null,
  };
  row.fill(cellDS);
  let gameBoard = Array(3);
  gameBoard.fill(row);
  console.log("board created");
  return gameBoard;
};
```

when I change the cell ID of the first element of the first row I get this result:

```
[[
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
],
[
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
],
[
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
  { isClicked: false, toPlayer: null, cellID: 1 },
]]
```

The same goest for isClicked and toPlayer.

Vuex code:

```
const state = { gameBoard: [] };
const getters = {
  getGameBoard: (state) => state.gameBoard,
};
const actions = {
  createBoard: ({ commit }) => {
    commit("setBoard");
  },
  editBoard: ({ commit }) => {
    commit("changeBoard");
  },
};
const mutations = {
  setBoard: (state) => {
    state.gameBoard = createBoard();
  },
  changeBoard: (state) => {
    console.log("Before: " + state.gameBoard[0][0]["cellID"]);
    state.gameBoard[0][0]["cellID"] = 1;
    console.log("After: " + state.gameBoard[0][0]["cellID"]);
    console.log("After: " + state.gameBoard[0][1]["cellID"]);
  },
}
```

---

Solution:
fill() creates an exact static copy of the element across the application and you can't simply use forEach on empty arrays like Array(3) will return [ , , ] which in itself is meaningless(undifiend).
So you may fill it with nulls and then use forEach() on it.

Comment: you can't simply use forEach on [ , , ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about objects in JS and the difference between value types and object types. In your case `fill` method just fills an array with the same object and if you change some field of this object it changes in all entries of the array because this is the exact same object. This array just stores a reference to this object but not a copy of it.

If you wish to create independent copies of this object you should create them in `for` loop to fill each element of the array by its own copy of the object.

```
for (let ind=0; ind< row.length; ind++) {
  row[ind] = Object.assign({}, cellDS); 
}
```

Please keep in mind that using `Object.assign` you do not copy all inner object props but only value type props. Object type props would point to the same objects as they are in the original object.
To make a deep copy of an object you should use something like `cloneDeep` function from `lodash` package.

Comment: I tried using your snippet but it returned the same empty array from Array(3)

Comment: What worked so far is filling them with null then using forEach to produce the required array
row.fill(null);
  row.forEach((x, y) => {
    row[y] = Object.assign({}, cellDS);
    console.log(x, y,  cellDS);
  });

Comment: Sorry, `forEach` does not take into account empty elements of an array. You should use a simple `for`. See updated answer

Comment: pre-filling the empty array with nulls works as well if you may please update the answer with this

Comment: If you will wish to pass a length of an array as a param then you should use my solution becuase you can indicate dynamic amount of nulls